# switch gone bad, syntax error?

Tags: ios, switch-statement

For some reason this switch statement don't want to recognise my view controller classes names nor the adhering variables (IndexViewController adhere indexVC). If I were to do it in a regular if or without dependency statements, it does recognise the same piece of code. I actually looked up the syntax of switch, because I thought my mind had leaked some memory. But syntax seems alright. Can anybody point out my error? Thanks

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        IndexViewController *indexVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IndexViewController"];
        [self.currentVC presentViewController:indexVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        break;
    case 1:
        ProtectionViewController *proVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProViewController"];
        [self.currentVC presentViewController:proVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        break;
    case 2:
        UsersViewController *usersVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UsersViewController"];
        [self.currentVC presentViewController:usersVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        break;
    case 3:
        StatisticsViewController *statisticsVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StatisticsViewController"];
        [self.currentVC presentViewController:statisticsVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        break;

    default:
        NSLog(@"We dont beleive in defaults");
        break;
}

}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow highlighting is not based on the app, it is just generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the case-local variables scope:

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0: {
        IndexViewController *indexVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IndexViewController"];
        [self.currentVC presentViewController:indexVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        break;
    }
    case 1: {
        ...
    }
    ...
```

Add the braces.

Comment: It's okay.  I'm sure there are dupes of this.  It's fairly common and frustrating.

Comment: true, I think the break; got me